# Revealing Module Pattern - Unit Testing with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

After a brief romance with the revealing module pattern I've come to realise a set-back when it comes to unit-testing modules. I cannot however decide if it is my approach to testing a module or whether there is some form of work-around.

Consider the following code:

```
var myWonderfulModule = (function () {
  function publicMethodA (condition) {
    if(condition === 'b') {
      publicMethodB();
    }
  }

  function publicMethodB () {
    // ...
  }

  return {
    methodA : publicMethodA,
    methodB : publicMethodB
  }
}());
```

If I wanted to test (using Jasmine) the various paths leading through publicMethodA to publicMethodB. I might write a small test like so:

```
it("should make a call to publicMethodB when condition is 'b'", function() {
  spyOn(myWonderfulModule , 'publicMethodB');
  myWonderfulModule.publicMethodA('b');
  expect(myWonderfulModule.publicMethodB).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

If I understand correctly, there's a copy of publicMethodB within the closure that cannot be changed. Even if I change myWonderfulModule.publicMethodB afterwards:

```
myWonderfulModule.publicMethodB = undefined;
```

calling `myWonderfulModule.publicMethodA` will still run the original version of B.

The example above is of course simplified but there are plenty of scenarios I can think of where it would be convenient to unit test conditional paths through a method.

Is this a limitation of the revealing module pattern or simply a misuse of unit testing? If not what work-arounds are available to me? I'm considering moving to something like RequireJS or reverting back to non-modular code.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cant test the intern methodes of a closure. And you also shouldn't spy on it. Think about about your module as a black box. You put something in and you get something out. All you should test is that the thing you get out of your module is the one that you expect.

Spying on methodes in your module makes not much sense. Think about it. You spy on it, the test passes. Now you change the functionality so it creates a bug, the test still passes cause the function is still called but you never mention the bug. If you just test the thing that cames out you dont need to spy on internal methodes cause, that they are called is implicite when the outcome of the module is what you expect.

So in your case there is no thing that goes in and nothing comes out. This makes not much sense but I believe that your module interacts with DOM or makes an ajax call. This are things that you can test (DOM) or you should spy on (ajax).

You should also make you self familiar with [Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). These are patterns that will make your modules much more easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the keyword "this" when you call publicMethodB() from publicMethodA() it will work. For example:

```
var myWonderfulModule = (function () {
    function publicMethodA (condition) {
        if(condition === 'b') {
            this.publicMethodB();
        }
    }

    function publicMethodB () {
        // ...
    }

    return {
        methodA : publicMethodA,
        methodB : publicMethodB
    }
}());
```